# Can't create a new sheet in GoogleColab and make calculcation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlsx, google-colaboratory

I have an xlsx file on my computer with initial data (value) - two sheets were created. I decide to calculate some value in sheet1 and in sheet2. After this I try to save the result, but when I download a file from GoogleColab and get my start file with initial values. 
And I don't know how to creat a new Sheet3 and make this calcuation in it: copy one column from Sheet1 and another column Sheet2 and make `P_roz = P_nav + P-osvit` the result in a new column in Sheet3.

How to download the xlsx file with the result in picture 2 and picture 4?

```py
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
    !pip install -q xlrd

    import pandas as pd 
    import numpy as np

    # Works with Sheet1

    df_1 = pd.read_excel('my_path', name_sheet = 'Sheet1')

    df_1['T_potyz'] = round((((1 / df_1['K_potyz']**2) - 1))**(1/2.0),3)

    df_1['P_nav, кВт'] = df_1['P_ust, кВт']\
    * df_1['K_poputy1']

    df_1['Q_nav, кВАр'] = round(df_1['P_ust, кВт']\
    * df_1['T_potyz'],3)

    df_1['S_nav, кВА'] = round((df_1['P_nav, кВт']**2\
                                            + df_1['Q_nav, кВАр']**2)\
    **(1/2.0),3)

    df_1['P_nav, кВт'].sum(), df_1['Q_nav, кВАр'].sum(), df_1['S_nav, кВА'].sum()
    sum_row1 = df_1[['P_nav, кВт', 'Q_nav, кВАр', 'S_nav, кВА']].sum()
    sum_row1

    # transpose the data and convert the Series to a DataFrame so that it is easier to concat onto our existing data. 
    #The T function allows us to switch the data from being row-based to column-based.

    df_sum1 = pd.DataFrame(data = sum_row1).T
    df_sum1

    # to add the missing columns.

    df_sum1 = df_sum1.reindex(columns = df_1.columns)
    df_sum1

    # add it to our existing one using append.

    df_final_1 = df_1.append(df_sum1, ignore_index = True)
    df_final_1.tail()

    # Works with Sheet2

    df_2 = pd.read_excel('my_path', sheet_name='Sheet2') 

    K_po = float(input("Коефіцієнт попиту загально освітлення: "))

    df_2['P_ust'] = (round(df_2['k'] * df_2['P_put'] * 10**-3 * 
                           df_2['A, м'] * df_2['B, м'],3))

    df_2['P_osvit'] = round(K_po * df_2['P_ust'],3)

    df_2['T_potyz2'] = round((((1 / df_2['K_poputy2']**2) - 1))**(1/2.0),3)

    df_2['Q_osvit'] = round(df_2['P_osvit'] * df_2['T_potyz2'],3)

    df_2['S_osvit'] = round((df_2['P_osvit']**2\
                                            + df_2['Q_osvit']**2)\
    **(1/2.0),3)

    df_2['P_osvit'].sum(), df_2['Q_osvit'].sum(), df_2['S_osvit'].sum()

    sum_row2 = df_2[['P_osvit', 'Q_osvit', 'S_osvit']].sum()
    sum_row2

    df_sum2 = pd.DataFrame(data = sum_row2).T
    df_sum2

    df_sum2 = df_sum2.reindex(columns = df_2.columns)
    df_sum2

    df_final2 = df_2.append(df_sum2, ignore_index = True)
    df_final2.tail()

    # Here I want create a new Sheet3 and make some calculation

    P_roz = df_1['P_nav, кВт'] + df_2['P_osvit']
    Q_roz = df_1['Q_nav, кВАр'] + df_2['Q_osvit']
    S_roz = (P_roz**2 + Q_roz**2)**(1 / 2.0)

    frame_data3 = {'P_roz' : [P_roz], 'Q_roz' : [Q_roz], 'S_roz' : [S_roz]}
    df_4 = pd.DataFrame(frame_data3)
    df_4
```

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oahsz.jpg)  [Sheet 1 + sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSJT9.jpg) [Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfync.jpg) [Sheet 2 + sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oahsz.jpg)

Comment: please edit your question and add your images into it

Comment: I added the images links

Comment: I add images as you say